# Javascript HTML .children traversal

Tags: javascript, html, dom, traversal

I'm trying to go through all of the elements in the document and pull the ones with a target class name. Importantly, I'm needing to do it without the use of `document.getElementsByClassName(className)` / `document.querySelectorAll`, etc. — that's the point of this learning exercise.

Here's the javascript:

```
var getElementsByClassName = function(className){
  var rootElem = document.body;
  var collectionResult = [];
  if (rootElem.getAttribute("class") == className) {
    collectionResult.push(rootElem);
  };
  var nextTier = function(collectionResult, rootElem) {
    var thisTier = rootElem.children;
    for (i=0; i<thisTier.length; i++) {
      var classes = thisTier[i].getAttribute("class");
      if (classes != undefined && classes.includes(className)) {
        collectionResult.push(thisTier[i]);
      };
      var childrenArray = thisTier[i].children; 
      if (childrenArray.length > 0) {
        nextTier(collectionresult, childrenArray)
      };
    };
  };
  nextTier(collectionResult, rootElem);
  return collectionResult;
};
```

Here's the section of the HTML structure I'm having trouble with:

```
<p>
  <div class="somediv">
    <div class="innerdiv">
      <span class="targetClassName">yay</span>
    </div>
   </div>
 </p>
```

The code works for the rest of the page with any number of non-nested elements. But as soon as `var childrenArray = thisTier[i].children` get to the `div.somediv` element, it has `childrenArray == undefined` rather than pulling the `div.innerdiv` element.

Am I misunderstanding how `element.children` works?

Comment: *"Importantly, I'm needing to do it without the use of `document.getElementsByClassName(className)`, that's the point of the exercise."* Actively....resisting...suggesting...`document.querySelectorAll("." + className);`... ;-)

Comment: Seriously: When you say it's the point of the exercise, is it because it's a learning exercise, or because you need to support IE8?

Comment: Haha sorry.. It's a learning exercise.

Comment: use childNodes instead.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes

Comment: I was trying to use children instead of childNodes so that it would only pull the actual elements.. I think that may be part of my misunderstanding.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I always smile when I see you participating ^.^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be overcomplicating things.

```js
function getElementsByClassName(className, root) {
  if(!root) root = document.documentElement;
  return [].reduce.call(root.children, function(arr, child) {
    if(child.classList.contains(className)) arr.push(child);
    return arr.concat(getElementsByClassName(className, child))
  }, []);
}
```

```js
function getElementsByClassName(className, root) {
  if(!root) root = document.documentElement;
  return [].reduce.call(root.children, function(arr, child) {
    if(child.classList.contains(className)) arr.push(child);
    return arr.concat(getElementsByClassName(className, child))
  }, []);
}
console.log(getElementsByClassName("targetClassName"));
```

```html
<div class="somediv targetClassName">
  <div class="innerdiv">
    <span class="targetClassName">yay1</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="somediv targetClassName">
  <div class="innerdiv targetClassName">
    <span class="targetClassName">yay2</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="somediv">
  <div class="innerdiv">
    <span class="targetClassName">yay3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[Array.prototype.flatMap](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) is an effective tool for flattening trees (like DOM) to an array of values (like a list of elements) -

```js
function getElementsByClassName (node, query) {   
  function matchAll (children) {
    return Array
      .from(children)
      .flatMap(c => getElementsByClassName(c, query))
  }
  if (node.classList && node.classList.contains(query))
    return [ node, ...matchAll(node.childNodes) ]
  else
    return matchAll(node.childNodes)
}

const result =
  getElementsByClassName(document, "targetClassName")
  
console.log(result)

// [ <div class="somediv targetClassName">…</div>
// , <span class="targetClassName">yay1</span>
// , <span class="targetClassName">yay2</span>
// , <span class="targetClassName">yay3</span>
// ]
```

```html
<div class="somediv targetClassName">
  <div class="innerdiv">
    <span class="targetClassName">yay1</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="somediv">
  <div class="innerdiv">
    <span class="targetClassName">yay2</span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="somediv">
  <div class="innerdiv">
    <span class="targetClassName">yay3</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This was fantastic. I was being stubborn and didn't even consider underscore for making my life easier with all of those loops and conditions.  
I did make one change:I removed the root argument from the main function and added var root = document.documentElement at the beginning.

Comment: @WesTyler, yeah you won't see me using jquery/underscore/lodash for anything really. I don't think you should remove the first argument tho, because then you'll only ever be able to search the *entire* DOM. For example, what if you wanted to find all elements with className inside `<div id="searchHere">`? With the API I provided, it would allow you to do that; which is exactly what the native getElementsByClassName API supports as well.